# Summation error (Sum) in Entity Framework and MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I use MySQL & Entity Framework (NET 5 / NET Core 3.1). I have a ‘Users’ table created based on the ‘User’ class:

```
public class User
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; } // int!
}
```

I can sum up the ages of all users:

```
var result = dbContext.Users.Sum(s => s.Age); // Ok
```

But, if the **Age property** is **short** or **byte**, then there will be an **error**. Why can't I sum fields like short or byte?!

I use for NET Core 3.1:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.11
- MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.22

I use for NET 5:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2
- MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0-m8.0.23

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to do this, but there isn't a translation for Convert functions to (generic) SQL:

```
var result = dbContext.Users.Sum(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Age));
```

This should work instead:

```
var result = dbContext.Users
    .Select(x => x.Age) // We only need one field, not the whole user object.
    .ToArray() // Run the SQL and bring over the array of short/byte
    .Sum(); // Client-side Sum method accepts byte or short.
```